# Is there a way to Make sure all active sessions in App pool are closed before recycling

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I need to recycle a IIS application pool for once a week and before recycling need to make sure all active sessions in App pool are closed.
Is there a way? using .net.

Answer (score 4):

The IIS recycling is usually "overlapped", meaning that **requests** aren't cut off: running requests are allowed to continue, while new requests are served by the new pool-instance. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735206(v=ws.10)).

But this doesn't help you for **sessions** (which span multiple requests). An InProc Session will be abandoned by a recycle. You could however store the session-state out-of-process, with StateServer or SqlServer, so it is safe from recycles. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)).

Answer (score 0):

How might that be possible? A session can take many minutes to be shut down. So it is impractical to wait for them.

I think you are asking the wrong question. You should ask "Can I prevent all sessions being destroyed on a recycle?". Answer: Yes. Use `StateServer` mode.